# Calling Workbooks.Open

Tags: excel, vbscript

This VBScript errs as "unknown runtime error", on the VBScript line that calls the application object's RUN method, which I'm quite sure I'm using correctly, syntactically.

With only one workbook open under the application object, I probably don't even need to prefix it with the Workbookname.
It appears the previous line (which sets the **wb** variable to the application object's **Workbooks.Open** method, does not open.  Nor does it err, nor does it "eventually" open. The path is correct, the filename is correct, there is no `On Error Resume Next` in my VBScript.
How can the workbook not open and not error?

I hope I am wrong in thinking there is a "wait/pause" issue.  Acting directly on the Excel object model, it seems like the VBScript code waiting until the excelapp object has opened the workbook should be a given?

```vb
dim excelapp, wb
set excelapp = createobject("excel.application")
excelapp.enableevents=true
excelapp.visible=true
set wb = excelapp.workbooks.open("C:\Users\John\Desktop\Scheduled Jobs from Isaac\Availability.xlsb")
'MSGBOX "SHOULD BE OPEN"
excelapp.windowstate = -4137    'value for constant xlMaximized acccording to msdn
excelapp.caption = "Running AVAILABILITY - Please WAIT..."
excelapp.run "Availability.xlsb!ChangeAndCopyFile"
```

Comment: Can you do a `If wb is Nothing Then Msgbox "hi"` to debug?  Also why not use the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library's FileSystemObject to detect if the file exists?  Also, you can engineer a pause/wait using VBScript's InputBox  http://wsh2.uw.hu/ch08b.html

Comment: As to your last question -- highlight the block of code and then press `Ctrl + k`

Comment: Have you tried a file path for the Excel file without spaces?

Comment: `Dir(FilePath)` will return the file name if the file exist.  `Len(Dir(FilePath))` will return a number > 0 it the file exists.  Since a number <> 0 will evaluate as True then  `If Len(Dir( "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Scheduled Jobs from Isaac\Availability.xlsb")) then` will execute if the file exists.

Comment: The problem is probably in `ChangeAndCopyFile`. .  Can you post that code?

Comment: OK, first I appreciate all your input - I did actually try a lot of debugging similar to what u suggested, that's why i say i "know" it opened and did not err on that line. i believe it was hidden, also that Application.Run "workbookname!macroname" is not sufficient

Comment: the way i got it working is to FIRST set wb as SET WB = GETOBJECT("PATHTOEXCELWORKBOOK")  and after that, SET EXCELAPP = GETOBJECT(,"EXCEL.APPLICATION"), then it all worked. Also Thomas Inzina good question--there was ALSO a problem in that code, whre it tried to close the host workbook, which conflicted with my vbscript.  i will post answer with final script.

Comment: @JohnColeman thank you - very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

final vbscript code i used, for better or worse:

```
dim excelapp, wb
'set excelapp = createobject("excel.application")
'excelapp.enableevents=true
'excelapp.visible=true
'set wb = excelapp.workbooks.open("C:\Users\John\Desktop\ScheduledJobsfromIsaac\Availability.xlsb")
'although I don't know why the above line is silently failing, i'm going to use an alternate method I read on S.O.:
set wb = GetObject("C:\Users\John\Desktop\ScheduledJobsfromIsaac\Availability.xlsb")
set excelapp = getobject(,"excel.application")
excelapp.enableevents=true
excelapp.visible=true
excelapp.windowstate = -4137    'value for constant xlMaximized acccording to msdn
excelapp.caption = "Running AVAILABILITY - Please WAIT..."
excelapp.run "Availability.xlsb!ChangeAndCopyFile"
wb.close(true)
excelapp.caption = "10 seconds to close - please WAIT..."
wscript.sleep 10000
excelapp.displayalerts=false
excelapp.quit
```

Answer (score 0):

probably, it helps if you can describe where and how you execute your vbscript above? is this coded in a .vbs file and execute with wscript.exe or cscript.exe, or embedded in a HTML or HTA?

If this is scripted in HTML, what browser are you using to view that? Please take note that almost all modern browsers will just ignore the vbscript silently.